# Traefik self-signed certificated wildcard subdomain in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, tls1.3

I'm looking for a solution to let traefik generate a wildcard certificate for my services. In fact in local development I do have multiple services sharing the same domain and currently I have to accept the certificate for each one.

I have 2 subdomains `front.domain.localhost` and `api.domain.localhost` and I would like a single certificate for both.

Here is a demo <kbd>docker-compose.yml</kbd>:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.5
    command:
      - --providers.docker
      - --entryPoints.http.address=:80
      - --entryPoints.http.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=https
      - --entryPoints.http.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https
      - --entryPoints.https.address=:443
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  front:
    image: traefik/whoami
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.front_router.rule=Host(`front.domain.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.routers.front_router.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.front_router.tls=true

  api:
    image: traefik/whoami
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.api_router.rule=Host(`api.domain.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.routers.api_router.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.api_router.tls=true
```

With this one I should accept 2 certificates (one for each subdomain).

I tried with various combination of `main` and `sans` as explained in https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#domains without success.

How can I achieve this ?